# C#: Custom number formatting in rigth to left languages

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, right-to-left

I am trying to write a number with a custom formatting in a **right-to-left** textbox(actually in a listview but whatever). here is the code:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
textbox1.Text = (18700).ToString("#,###",nfi);
```

instead of `18 700` i get `700 18`. can i fix this(get the required `18 700`) without manipulating the string after number to string conversion?

Comment: Your code is working right http://take.ms/FMqiJ

Comment: Try using NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo(); instead of NumberFormatInfo nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();

Comment: what is the flow direction of your `textbox1`?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad as i said it is right to left

Comment: @S.Petrosov you are missing something. the important part of my question is that the textbox is right-to-left. in your console application, you are printing the number as left to right

Comment: @S.Petrosov `new NumberFormatInfo()` didn't work either :(

Comment: @samadmontazeri yeah, sorry forgot about formatting right-to-left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a space, use a [no-break space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). It's character is `(char)0x00A0` or `'\u00A0'` in C#. You can also type it using keyboard using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>255</kbd>.

So you can set `NumberGroupSeparator` this way:

```
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = "\u00A0";
```

Comment: Why not `nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = "\u00A0";`? :-)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Mamnoon :) (Thank you) this answer works perfectly. I up-voted + accepted your answer. But for sake of completeness, can i do it with other characters too? for example if i want to use `'` for thousand separator?

Comment: @samadmontazeri You're welcome. There is a [left to right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark). It's a non-printable character that is used to set the way adjacent characters are grouped with respect to text direction. You can use it this way for space `nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = "\u200E" + " ";` or for other characters like `"'"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do such a little trick:

```
textBox1.Text = TurnString((18700).ToString("#,###", nfi));

public static string TurnString(string value)
{
    Stack<string> stack = new Stack<string>();
    foreach(string a in value.Split(' '))
    {
        stack.Push(a);
    }
    string result = string.Empty;
    while(stack.Count>0)
    {
        result += stack.Pop()+' ';
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: can i fix this(get the required 18 700) without manipulating the string after number to string conversion?

Comment: @samadmontazeri I can't say exactly, let's wait may be somebody more experienced in working with "right-to-left" textboxes knows how to do it